# Is it possible to find out the number of timesteps taken by the mesolve/sesolve method in QuTip?

Tags: simulation, qutip

I am simulating a Quantum System in QuTip using `qutip.sesolve`. As far as I understand it, the solver propagates the state into the future using time steps of different sizes, determined at each step. Is it possible to find out how many steps were necessary after the simulation is complete?